# Setting <p> tag width or getting it to scale

Tags: html, css, mobile, size, width

I recently created this website and it all looks fine etc on desktop and the same on mobile except the paragraphed text, it goes out of line.

If you view it on your mobile phone you will see what I mean. Basically the paragraphed text doesn't stay in-line with the images above on mobile devices, it shrinks to half the width, how do I get it to stay the same like on the desktop version?

http://www.callamsgraphics.co.uk/zarp/index.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try the meta tags in heder part of your html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head><title>
    <!-- your page title here-->
</title><meta http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="blendTrans(Duration=2.0)" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, height=device-height,
                                                       initial-scale=0.6" />

<!-- your code  here-->
</head>
<body>
<!-- your code  here-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems to of done the trick, but it has messed the background, just shows as pure black

Comment: I think when browsing in mobile device that extra backgroud will be wrapped.